# Migrate Hibernate3 to Hiberante 5 -> Failure due to event listener property is not present in LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hi I am trying to migrate code to Hibernate 5 getting issue

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="eventListeners">
            <map>
                <entry key="flush-entity">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="com.pack.classA" />
                        <bean class="org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener" />
                    </list>
                </entry>
             </map>
        </property>
```

Error:

```
**error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'eventListeners' of 
bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'eventListeners' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
```

could you please suggest any alternative soution?**